# Can't use UPN credentials with New-MoveRequest?

Tags: powershell, microsoft-office-365, exchange-2013

We're on a hybrid setup (Exchange 2013 on-prem), and MRSproxy is enabled and working. We want to archive our user's mailbox when they leave the company. So we want to migrate those mailbox from the Office 365 back to our on premise server. I've been trying to create a leaving script, and the `New-MoveRequest` cmdlet keeps on giving the following error:

```
The Mailbox Replication Service was unable to connect to the remote server using the credentials provided. Please check the credentials and try again. The call to 'https://webmail.blah.com/EWS/mrsproxy.svc' failed.
Error details: The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM'. --> The remote server returned an error:
(401) Unauthorized.. --> The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM'. --> The remote server returned an
error: (401) Unauthorized.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-MoveRequest], RemotePermanentException
    +9,Microsoft.Exchange.Man
   agement.Migration.MailboxReplication.MoveRequest.NewMoveRequest
    + PSComputerName        : outlook.office365.com
```

So I tested with `Test-MigrationServerAvailability -ExchangeRemoteMove  -RemoteServer webmail.blah.com -Credentials $UserName<#>` with the 3 following type of PSCredentials:

```
UserName1 : <domain>\<SamAccountName>

UserName2 : <SamAccountName>

UserName3 : <SamAccountName>@<domain> (UPN)
```

With `UserName1` and `UserName2` I get

```
RunspaceId         : 3966b356-0f49-46c3-9373-e914827fc6ed
Result             : Success
Message            :
ConnectionSettings : <ExchangeConnectionSettings HasAdminPrivilege="True" HasAutodiscovery="False" HasMrsProxy="True" AutodiscoverUrl="" IncomingEmailAddress="" IncomingRPCProxyServer="webmail.blah.ccom"
                     IncomingExchangeServer="webmail.blah.com" IncomingNSPIServer="" IncomingDomain="" IncomingUserName="UserName<#>" EncryptedIncomingPassword="something"
                     IncomingAuthentication="Basic" ServerVersion="" TargetDomainName="" SourceMailboxLegDn="" PublicFolderDatabaseServerLegacyDN="" IsPublicFolderMailboxesMigrationSource="False" />
SupportsCutover    : False
ErrorDetail        :
IsValid            : True
Identity           :
ObjectState        : New
```

but with `UserName3` I get :

```
RunspaceId         : 3966b356-0f49-46c3-9373-e914827fc6ed
Result             : Failed
Message            : The connection to the server 'webmail.blah.com' could not be completed.
ConnectionSettings :
SupportsCutover    : False
ErrorDetail        : Microsoft.Exchange.Migration.MigrationServerConnectionFailedException: The connection to the server 'webmail.blah.com' could not be completed. --->
                     Microsoft.Exchange.MailboxReplicationService.RemotePermanentException: The Mailbox Replication Service was unable to connect to the remote server using the credentials provided. Please check
                     the credentials and try again. The call to 'https://webmail.blah.com/EWS/mrsproxy.svc' failed. Error details: The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. The
                     authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM'. --> The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.. --> The HTTP request is unauthorized with client
                     authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM'. --> The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. --->
                     Microsoft.Exchange.MailboxReplicationService.RemotePermanentException: The call to 'https://webmail.blah.com/EWS/mrsproxy.svc' failed. Error details: The HTTP request is unauthorized with client
                     authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM'. --> The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.. --->
                     Microsoft.Exchange.MailboxReplicationService.RemotePermanentException: The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from
                     the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM'. ---> Microsoft.Exchange.MailboxReplicationService.RemotePermanentException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
                        --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
                        --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
                        --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
                        at Microsoft.Exchange.MailboxReplicationService.MailboxReplicationServiceFault.<>c__DisplayClass97_0.<ReconstructAndThrow>b__0()
                        at Microsoft.Exchange.MailboxReplicationService.ExecutionContext.Execute(Action operation)
                        at Microsoft.Exchange.MailboxReplicationService.MailboxReplicationServiceFault.ReconstructAndThrow(String serverName, VersionInformation serverVersion)
                        at Microsoft.Exchange.MailboxReplicationService.WcfClientWithFaultHandling`2.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<CallService>b__0()
                        at Microsoft.Exchange.Net.WcfClientBase`1.CallService(Action serviceCall, String context)
                        at Microsoft.Exchange.MailboxReplicationService.WcfClientWithFaultHandling`2.CallService(Action serviceCall, String context)
                        at Microsoft.Exchange.Migration.MigrationExchangeProxyRpcClient.CanConnectToMrsProxy(Fqdn serverName, Guid mbxGuid, NetworkCredential credentials, LocalizedException& error)
                        --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
                        at Microsoft.Exchange.Migration.DataAccessLayer.ExchangeRemoteMoveEndpoint.VerifyConnectivity()
                        at Microsoft.Exchange.Management.Migration.MigrationService.Endpoint.TestMigrationServerAvailability.InternalProcessEndpoint(Boolean fromAutoDiscover)
IsValid            : True
Identity           :
ObjectState        : New
```

Looking at the TechNet article for both `New-MoveRequest` and `Test-MigrationServer` the `Credentials/RemoteCredential` parameter should accept UPN usernames.

Is this a limit with Exchange 2013? I can Remote-PSSession to the on premise Exchange server with the UPN username, and import the CMDlet, so I'm at a lost why it doesn't work with `New-MoveRequest` and `Test-MigrationServer` loaded from Office 365?

Comment: Have you seen this article: https://www.alitajran.com/move-mailbox-from-exchange-online-to-on-premises/. Basic auth is not supported anymore by the way by M365, it has been disabled a few months ago for all tenants.

Comment: That's correct, but it was supported at the time when this question was asked.

Answer (score 0):

It could just be the implementation of the CMDLET and how it is negotiating the connection.  Your endpoint is configured with Negotiate, so the client and server should decide if you are using kerberos or NTLM.  In your failed attempt it did not detect either correctly, and tried to fall back to Basic Auth - which your server is not configured to support.

NTLM does not support the UPN format, and you did not have a kerberos ticket, so this could be the reason.  You generally don't run into this with Windows clients/servers often as most applications seem to take care of reformatting the username reqeust.  However if your samAccountName and UPN pre-fix are different then the credentials won't match.

I would be sure your samAccountName and UPN prefixes match on the account.  If not, or if they still fail, you should be able to enable basic auth on EWS.  This should allow it to fall back on the client side and be accepted on the server side.  Since this is an O365 connection, I think we can assume safely your already using HTTPS - which of course is critical if your using Basic Auth as the credentials are sent in plan text.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'm actually using `Basic` auth to connect to O365, and my `UPN` and `SamAccountName` both match. If I read this correctly, I need to enable Basic Auth my on premise Exchange so it'll accept UPN?

Comment: Without digging deeper into the problem and trying to replicate I would say yes - you will most likely have to enable Basic auth on your Exchange server.  I would try to only enable on the EWS endpoint and then attempt your command again (MRS is exposed thru EWS).